# Maximum eigenvalue of a matrix function

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Define the vector $\mathbf{w}=(w_{1},\ldots,w_{n})$ with each element
$w_{i}=\frac{e^{x_{i}}}{\sum_{k=1}^{n}e^{x_{k}}}$ for $i\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$
and define the matrix

$$A(x)\triangleq\mathbf{diag}(\mathbf{w})-\mathbf{w}\mathbf{w}^{\top}.$$

Clearly $A(x)=\mathbf{diag}(\mathbf{w})-\mathbf{w}\mathbf{w}^{\top}\preceq\mathbf{diag}(\mathbf{w})\preceq\mathbf{I}_{n\times n}$,
hence the maximum eigenvalue of $A(x)$ is bounded by $1$ for any
$x$.

Is $1$ the smallest upper bound on the largest eigenvalue of $A(x)$ that holds for all $x$, or is it possible to get a tighter bound on the largest eigenvalue that holds
for any $x$?

Any tips or suggestions will be much appreciated.

Comment: By Gerchgorin Theorem, the norm of A is at most 1/2 and you cannot do better than that

Comment: Thanks very much for the pointer @Exodd!